# walking along and processing files in directory in python

Tags: python, dir

I have huge data in a directory tree format like:
`c:/user/name/class/std/section I to VI [all section has individual folder i.e. 6 folder in total and all folder have 100+ files to be processed]`
I wrote a script in which if I give the folder containing the files e.g.`Section I` then it would process files inside using `glob.iglob`function.
Is it possible to write a script which can walk along directories by just entering one directory > processing file > leaving directory > entering different directory > and so on.
please help.

Comment: Take a look at the os.walk function http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk

Comment: @Levon thanx for your link...actually I'm new to Python, so it was quite helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing Abhisek's comment on Aragon's solution:

import os
folder = 'C:'

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for name in files:
        (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(name)
        if ext in "csv":
            print os.path.join(root, name)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code :

```
import os
folder = 'C:'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
    for name in dirs:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
```

**UPDATE:**

import os
    folder = 'C:'

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for name in files:
        nm, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
        if ext == ".csv":
            print os.path.join(root, name)
```

Comment: but suppose if i want to find and process *.csv files inside each folder, then what will be the easiest way..??

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
    # Do some processing
```

That will iterate through the root of the directory specified, for eg. `c:/user/name/class/std` and enter every folder contained in it, and give you the folders and files contained in them. With that you should be able to do what you need to processing wise.